How can I redact or remove entire line from pdf using either pymuPDF or other python libraries
I am currently working on formatting PDFs using pyMuPDF library in python. I have several tasks that involves formatting the PDF file as follows:

I need to remove empty lines so that the PDF file does not look dis-oriented. Now, I have tried the following code:

def remove_extra_lines_spaces(doc):
    for page_index, page in enumerate(doc):
        blocks = page.get_text("dict", sort=True)["blocks"]
        empty_line_count = 0
        for index, block in enumerate(blocks):
            try:
                for line in block["lines"]:
                    for span in line["spans"]:
                        if span["text"].strip() == "":
                            if empty_line_count >= 1:
                                page.add_redact_annot(line["bbox"], cross_out=True)
                            empty_line_count += 1
                        else:
                            empty_line_count = 0

            except:
                pass
        
        page.apply_redactions(images=2, graphics=2, text=0)

    return doc

Here, I am keeping track of the empty lines and if I find 2 consecutive lines, then I am removing it. But, this is not removing the entire lines. Here, is the screenshot of what it does when I am simply redacting it without applying it.

As one can see in the uploaded picture, I am able to locate the lines with extra spaces but I am unable to remove it.
Now, have anyone came across such problem and has already solved it or does anyone have any idea on how I go about solving it?

@KJ I understand your point. I saw the sample pdf that you have uploaded. So what you suggest is that I extract all the text and re-create entire pdf removing spaces?

Yes, I understand your point of playing around with the library. I did but I have a huge workload of documents are all of them have different structure and thus it is better to do it in word and the convert them back to PDF maintaining the layout.
